# Qual a forma correta, "agente" ou "a gente"?

Tags: significado, ortografia, diferenças

Vejo muitos erros relacionados com a utilização das duas palavras. Qual a forma correta?

Comment: Mine’s Bond – James Bond.

Comment: Muito interessante [estas dicas de português](http://www.umexerciciotododia.com.br/2016/09/o-certo-e-agente-ou-gente.html).
*Agente* e *a gente* aparentemente é algo bobo mas pega muitas pessoas de surpresa.

Comment: Esta pergunta ficava muito melhor com exemplos, uma ou duas frases.

Comment: Qual é a forma correta para qual sentido?? Os sentidos são differentes. Essa pergunta não merece tantos pontos.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As duas estão corretas, porém seus significados são diferentes.

*Agente* é a pessoa que realiza algo.

*A gente* é uma locução pronominal equivalente ao pronome pessoal reto nós.

Exemplos:

- A gente vai à casa das primas depois do almoço.
- Aquele agente da policia federal conseguiu prender o ladrão.

Comment: Não esquece do agente secreto ... porém, a gente secreto é mais difícil.

Comment: Lembre-se que usar "a gente" é uma forma coloquial. Se possível, use sempre "nós", é mais formal.

Nós vamos à casa das primas depois do almoço.

Answer (score 3):

*Agente* e *a gente* estão plenamente corretas.

*Agente* é um substantivo. É uma pessoa (individualismo). Ex.:

> James Bond é um agente secreto.

*A gente* expressa o significado de coletividade. Ex.:

> A gente deve votar com mais consciência (nós).

A conjugação verbal deve observar a terceira pessoa do singular.

Fonte: [Aprender Português.](http://aprenderportugues.com.br/agente-ou-a-gente-diferenca/)

Answer (score 1):

Agente e a gente fazem sim parte do dicionário da língua portuguesa e estão super corretas as palavras. O problema é como as pessoas utilizam. Aí vão alguns exemplos

*Agente* é um substantivo. É uma pessoa (individualismo). Ex.:

O agente de saúde veio visitar minha casa hoje.

*A gente* expressa o significado de coletividade. Ex.:

A gente deve se unir no final de semana (nós).

Lembrando que é importante que a conjugação verbal esteja na terceira pessoa do singular.

Fonte: [Ache Português](https://www.acheportugues.com.br/como-escreve/agente-ou-a-gente.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ambas formas estão corretas, porém, hoje em dia é muito comum pessoas usarem *agente* no lugar de *a gente*, se algum nativo usar *agente* no lugar de  *a gente*, não precisa se preocupar, isso acontece frequentemente.

*A gente* = nós.

*Agente* = James Bond, agente 007, agente federal.

Answer (score -2):

Agente seria uma autoridade. Exemplo senhor agente (polícia)

Gente seria nos (grupo de pessoas)

Comment: Anselmo por favor tente fundamentar um bocado mais as suas respostas, o sistema faz um alerta de baixa qualidade quando assim é.

Comment: Faz um [tour](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/tour). Todas as tuas respostas tem qualidade muito baixa. 

Tal como os restantes utilizadores você tem que fundamentar a sua resposta. Nem é preciso ser sempre com bases em fontes, nem muito longas, a resposta do @meuChapéu é prova disso.

Tente perceber que algumas das perguntas tentam encontrar algum tipo de prova/explicação

Comment: Obrigado, vou procurar melhor

Answer (score -2):

A gente no sentido de nós é tomado como erro crasso. Em Portugal, desde pequeno que ouvia: "Agente é da polícia", para corrigir essa tendência feia de se referir a nós com a expressão "a gente".

A gente pode-se dizer quando referida a um grupo de pessoas que partilham algum tipo de característica.

Comment: A locução pronominal *a gente* é um facto da língua portuguesa, mais que consagrado pelo uso, e reconhecido nos melhores dicionários e gramáticas. Qualquer um tem o direito de usar exclusivamente *nós* e nunca *a gente*; é uma opção estilística. Mas acusar de erro quem segue opção diferente, isso sim é erro crasso.